# Create a job to save a secret in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I have created a job that runs the following command (job-command.sh):

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
{
 "apiVersion": "v1",
 "kind": "Secret",
 "metadata": {
   "name": "my-secret-name",
   "namespace": "my-namespace"
 },
 "data": {
   "cert": "my-certificate-data"
 },
 "type": "Opaque"
}
EOF
```

The job looks like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "my-name-job1"
  namespace: "my-namespace"
  labels:
    app: "my-name"
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-name
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: my-name-sa
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: myrepo
        image: "repo:image"
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        command: ["sh", "-c"]
        args:
          - |-
              /job-command.sh
```

And the rbac like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-name-sa
  namespace: my-namespace

---------------------------

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-name-rolebinding
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: "{{ .Chart.Name }}"
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: my-name-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-name-sa

---------------------------

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: my-name-role
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: "{{ .Chart.Name }}"
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
rules:
  - apiGroups:      ['']
    resources:      ['secrets']
    verbs:          ["get", "watch", "list", "create", "update", "patch"]
```

I'm getting the following issue:

```
"error: error validating "STDIN": error validating data: the server does not allow access to the requested resource; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false"
```

I don't understand what's wrong... the service account used by the job should give access to save secrets...

Comment: could you try adding the namespace field in the `subjects` section as well for the serviceAccount?

Comment: Just tried and unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: you can also try running the command: `kubectl auth can-i create secret --as=system:serviceaccount:<namespace>:<serviceaccountname> [-n <namespace>]` to see if the permissions are setup correctly.

Comment: Also, may be try quoting the chart, heritage, etc field in your yamls as they are done in some but not in others.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia Very interesting, I didn't know I could test it. I got a "yes" when running `can-i`. The quotes are only due to the fact that I use variables in my actual code but replaced them with text for better clarity. I m still stuck though... It seems that the Job is not using the ServiceAccount or that it's not correctly binding the role. Let me know what you think. Thanks

Comment: I'd reckon this is not the issue of `serviceAccount`, `Role` and `Rolebinding` as I used you exact examples with a `google/cloud-sdk` image which I exec'd into and run your `kubectl apply -f - ...`. I'm more inclined to the idea that the issue lies in your image. Could you please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of it? If not please try to do as I told and see if it works for you.

Comment: @DawidKruk Sure, https://github.com/grapevine-ai/letsencrypt I have created a a deployment to manually run the scripts and I still get the issue... You can see the template here: https://github.com/grapevine-ai/public-charts/blob/master/helm/charts/openvpn/templates/letsencrypt.jobs.pre-install.yaml

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the link of the image itself: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/grapevineai/letsencrypt

Comment: When I used image: `ployst/letsencrypt` I had the same issue as you (huge mismatch of versions: client `1.6`, server: `1.19`). When I used your newly created image: `grapevineai/letsencrypt` it worked fine for me. Are you experiencing the same issues on your new image? Please check the `YAML` manifest which image are you using. Alos which Kubernetes version are you running this on?

Comment: I created this image especially for this purpose (no mismatch between versions). My server is 1.17.15 which is what I've set in the image for the client. I still get the issue but I have tried to put the flag `--validate=false` in the save_certs.sh script and it worked. I don't know the implication for the security though. The fact that it worked makes me wonder if the issue is really an rbac issue. I'm wondering if the problem lies in the generation of the 2048 bits key since this process doesn't even finish when I get the error.

Comment: I also tried to reproduce locally and it worked with `bitnami/kubectl:latest` image. So, the rbac is certainly not a problem. I had to add the following line in the bash script `#!/bin/bash` though but don't think it is necessary.

Comment: @ncohen apologies for a late reply. Could you tell more about the generation of this 2048 bit key? Could you share to `job-command.sh` without any PII? Also please try to use the images that I and Krishna used and tell if it's feasible for you in that regard.

Comment: @DawidKruk Thanks but I have decided to put the `--validate=false` flag

Comment: @ncohen as you've found a workaround for your issue please consider creating an answer to give more visibility on possible workaround for other community members.

Comment: @DawidKruk Well, that's not really a workaround, it simply is bypassing validation in my docker image...it's not a solution